# my flutter app keeps rebuilding itself when i navigate between screens on my bottom navigation

Tags: android, flutter, dart

my app keeps rebulding itself when i try to navigate between pages on the bottom navigation, it becomes a problem when i am trying to run a function only once when the user opens the app, but my app keeps rebuilding the homescreen, i have three screens, the third screen doesnt rebuild, only homescreen,i tried deleting any init state or dispose function to see if that was the cause but no luck, i need it to stop rebuilding so many times within the app because i have functions that should run only once

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/styles/texts.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/styles/colors.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/widgets/result.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
    import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRagePicker;
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    import 'package:numberpicker/numberpicker.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_picker/flutter_picker.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:hotel_search/detail1.dart';
    
    import 'package:hotel_search/common/icons.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/common/stub_data.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/common/theme.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/parallax_page_view.dart';
    import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/splash.dart';
    import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:custom_navigation_bar/custom_navigation_bar.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/start.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:hotel_search/model.dart';
    import 'package:show_up_animation/show_up_animation.dart';
    import 'package:ripple_backdrop_animate_route/ripple_backdrop_animate_route.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    import 'package:overlay_screen/overlay_screen.dart';
    import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
    
    import 'package:hotel_search/FadeAnimation.dart';
    import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
    import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
    
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  Home createState() => Home();
}

class Home extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Home createState() => Home();
  static bool ready = true;

  final List<String> hotelCategories = StubData().hotelCategories;
  final List<capitalCard> capital = StubData().capital;
  final List<livingstoniaCard> livingstonia = StubData().livingstonia;
  final List<mountsocheCard> mountsoche = StubData().mountsoche;
  final List<mzuzuCard> mzuzu = StubData().mzuzu;
  final List<lilongweCard> lilongwe = StubData().lilongwe;
  final List<kuchaweCard> kuchawe = StubData().kuchawe;
  final List<nkopolaCard> nkopola = StubData().nkopola;

  int checkedItem = 0;

  static const PickerData2 = '''
[
    [
        1 ,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    ],
    [
       1 ,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
    ],
    [
        "Adults"
    ]
]
    ''';

  static var datePicked = "Click here";
  static var roomPicked = "Click here";
  bool start = false;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeData = HotelConceptThemeProvider.get();

    return Scaffold(
        key: _drawerKey,
        drawerEdgeDragWidth: 0,
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[ListTile()],
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
          child: AppBar(
            bottomOpacity: 0.0,
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Text(
              "Sunbird Hotels",
              style: textStyles['appBar'],
            ),
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.grey[800],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'img/logo.jpg',
                    width: 34,
                    height: 34,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body:
```

Comment: Use `IndexedStack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 2 solution you can do

1- Use KeepAlive class, according to official doc (Mark a child as needing to stay alive even when it's in a lazy list that would otherwise remove it).

In code :

```
class YourStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {

//add with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to the state class

class _YourStatefulWidgetState extends State<YourStatefulWidget > with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  //add  super.build(context) under the build method
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  super.build(context);

  return //your widget

   @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  }
 }
}
```

2-using another screen as your first screen with an async function, make it await your function  that only run once to finishes and then navigate with Navigator.pushReplacement to your home screen, this way you could remove your function form your home screen.

And this is a normal behaver by flutter to save the memory.